# wp8 app internet connection check and prevent unhandled shut down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure, windows-phone-8

I am encountering an unhandled error from no connection. How do I handle it? Do I need a try-catch or something similar?

Here is my code:

```
WebClient webClientx = new WebClient();
webClientx.DownloadStringCompleted += webClientx_DownloadStringCompleted;
webClientx.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://vdasco/" + + "&=" + card));
```

Also, how can I the vibrate phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check network before your webservice call using this

```
NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

reference is

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

Comment: @user3565698 - Can you post this as a Separate Question. You can copy and mark the below answer if its working. That will help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to Vibrate Phone using **.Net API.**

1. Import the Microsoft.Devices namespace.

   ```
   using Microsoft.Devices;
   ```
2. Get a reference to the vibration controller by using the static Default property of the VibrateController class.

   ```
   VibrateController testVibrateController = VibrateController.Default;
   ```
3. Start the vibration by calling the Start(TimeSpan) method of the VibrateController class. Specify the duration as a TimeSpan value.

   ```
   testVibrateController.Start(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
   ```
4. Stop vibration.

   ```
   testVibrateController.Stop();
   ```

Follow the below steps to Vibrate Phone using **Windows Runtime API.**

1. Import the Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification namespace.

   ```
   using Windows.Phone.Devices.Notification;
   ```
2. Get a reference to the vibration controller by calling the static GetDefault method of the VibrationDevice class.

   ```
   VibrationDevice testVibrationDevice = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
   ```
3. Start the vibration by calling the Vibrate method of the VibrationDevice class. Specify the duration as a TimeSpan value.

   ```
   testVibrationDevice.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
   ```
4. If necessary, stop the vibration by calling the Cancel method of the VibrationDevice class.

   ```
   testVibrationDevice.Cancel();
   ```

Comment: This appears to be an answer to the OP's comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey buddy... this answer is the answer of the person asked question. You can see the question in the comment of accepted answer by the same person.

Comment: can you answer one one if you know how can i resresh a pivot page which have onnavigate webclient and i want to refresh webclient requests?